# Set viewport width where text starts to wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way in CSS (or JS but preferably CSS) to define the breakpoint where text starts to wrap. I'm using React 17/CRA and CSS modules.

I have a React app that has a header bar with two pieces of content. On the left-hand side is the three-word title of the app in an `h1` tag. On the right-hand side is the logged-in user's profile photo and name, composed of several elements within a `span`. If I narrow the viewframe, first the content overflows and then, if I narrow it more, the title of the app starts to wrap.

I would like the title to wrap before any overflow happens so all the content stays on the screen as long as possible. All the Googling I've done has only come up with info on `overflow-wrap` or `word-break`, which aren't what I'm looking for. The text is wrapping like I want it to, I'd just rather it did so sooner.

The code of my component is:

```js
import React from 'react'
import anonymousAvatar from './anonymousAvatar.jpg'
import styles from './dashboardHeader.module.css'

const DashboardHeader ({data}) => (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    <div className={styles.bar}>
      <span className={styles.headerContainer}>
        <h1 className={styles.header}>Three Word Title</h1>
      </span>
      <span className={styles.profile}>
        <div className={styles.profileText}>
          <p className={styles.textTop}>{data.name}</p>
          <p className={styles.textBottom}>{data.email}</p>
        </div>
        <img className={styles.avatar} src={data.image_url || anonymousAvatar} alt='User Avatar' referrerPolicy='no-referrer' />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default DashboardHeader
```

The CSS module I currently have is:

```
.root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerContainer {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.profile {
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  max-width: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.profileText {
  display: grid;
}

.textTop, .textBottom {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.025rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.textTop {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.textBottom {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.avatar {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #fff;
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Here is the component at the full width of my laptop screen:
[image]

Here it is at an intermediate width:
[image]

And here it is at the very narrow width where the text finally starts to wrap (notice there is still overflow):
[image]

Comment: Find the width in browser dev tools then set a mediaquery for it?

Comment: What I'm asking is what to put in the media query to force the text to wrap at a particular breakpoint.

Comment: **1)** Decrease width of the element at the breakpoint *( recommended )* or **2)**   put a `<br>` in the element with `display: none` until your breakpoint triggers. ex: `three word <br style='display:none' > title` then set it to `display: block` at your breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you! I had to do some errands but I'll try it when I'm back. If it works you can make it an answer & I'll accept it :)

Comment: Ok I added an answer with an example of the first solution mentioned. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments you can simply change the width of the element at your desired breakpoint like in the top blue div of the example below. I'm using animations to help you visualize the results but you would decrease the width of the element in question at your media query breakpoint. I recommend this method because it doesn't require you to increase your HTML markup.

```css
body, div, p, span {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: Arial;  
}
div {
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateY( -5rem );
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%; height: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #222; color: #eee;
}
div, div:nth-of-type( 1 ) p:first-of-type {
  animation-name: contract; animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: translateY( 5rem );
}
@keyframes contract { 100% { width: 25%; } }
p { 
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p:first-of-type {
  font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5rem; height: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
  }
  div:nth-of-type( 1 ) p:first-of-type::before,
  div:nth-of-type( 2 ) p:first-of-type::before {
    content: 'wraps first';
    position: absolute; top: -4rem;
    border-radius: 1rem; padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #07f; white-space: nowrap;
  }
  div:nth-of-type( 2 ) p:first-of-type::before {
    content: 'wraps last';
    top: auto; bottom: -4rem;
    background-color: #f07;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <p>three word title</p>
  <p>name <br> foo@gmail.com<span></span></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>three word title</p>
  <p>name <br> foo@gmail.com<span></span></p>
</div>
```

I'm simply using the `contract` animation to manually decrease the width of the paragraph in the first div before it's width is forced smaller by its container. If this doesn't work in your particular setup you could use hidden `<br>` elements with `display: none` until your desired breakpoint to set them to `block`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! This works brilliantly, it's doing just what I want now.